# How to call a keypress event by Jquery without pressing any keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to realize a keypress event for typing a string into an input elements by Jquery, I know Jquery can listen the event of keypress, keydown and keyup. But, what I want to do is using the Jquery to realize the action of keypress and put the value of which key I pressed into the input elements. Is that possible by jQuery to realize this task?

Comment: Do you want that jQuery fills in a textbox not actually with the pressed value key but with its keycode?

Comment: yes, this is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZRBpp?editors=101)**

```
$('.input').on('keypress', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).val(event.keyCode);
});

$( ".input" ).trigger( "keypress" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Target input element and bind to the "keyPress" event.
$('.input').on('keypress', function(event) {
  // Prevent the default action to stop the key character being entered into the field
  event.preventDefault();
  // Add the event's keyCode into the field
  $(this).val(event.keyCode);
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXNOQd?editors=101

Comment: Why the input element still empty as I have tested your code up there, I was thinking, the way we put a value into the input element is: $('#input').val(); But, from your code, I did not find this code, can you help me to modify it?

Comment: I've updated the code above now you've clarified the requirements in the question comments.

Comment: Thx, but I think you misunderstood my point. I would like to use Jquery to trigger a keypress event, but pressing any keyboard. Meanwhile, also input values into input element. Is that possible to realize?